# how to change parent view's height to fit child view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have one relative view that contains one listview. I am creating this relative view on run time and add contents (basically an string array) to my list view. I have set the listview width and height to "wrap_content".
The problem is my list parent relative view is not resizing to show my listview. it just shows first value of the list . 
I understand I have to override onmeasure method. So, how exactly can I get the height of my listview in onmeasure method so i can pass it to my parent view
I have read many problems like this but couldn't get it working.

One more thing getMeasuredHeight() returns 0 in my onmeasure() method.

**Update**

my main layout activity_main

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_route_search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

lo_block.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text_view" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my code
Frag.java

```
public class Frag extends Fragment {

private View mView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    showView();
    return mView;
}

public void showView() {

    block card = new block(getActivity());

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    card.setLayoutParams(params);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) mView.findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    vg.addView(card);
}

private class block extends RelativeLayout {
```

//      int listViewh = 0;
//      private float listViewHeight;

```
    public block(Context context) {
        super(context);

        View mView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.lo_block, this);

        ListView lst = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[] { "ad", "sfsd", "sfsf", "asfsfs" });

        lst.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public block(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public int getMinimumHeight() {

        return super.getMinimumHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
```

//          setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        }

```
}
```

}

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

My main activity
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,
            new Frag()).commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: forgot to mention, Relativelayout's width and height is also wrap_content.

Comment: result is same for that too. Just for the note, if set my listview's height to some pixels says "250dp" then my relative layout shows that so the only problem is give calculative height to relative view before it renders itself.

Comment: Not exactly,It works fine with normal activity but if I put this code in a fragment then it doesn't . Try this once with fragment also. Main activity xmlcontains one framelayout withing linearlayout.

Comment: I have update the full code as it is. Run it once pls let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I will be displaying a composite view. That text view is like header that will display some info and then the list view. I want to create this view multiple times and each added to scroll view one beneath the  other. The component of list view is dynamic and will be available on runtime only. So i want to set the height of this view to accommodate the both header(text view [fixed height ) and list view(whose height is variable ).  And I am using fragments it is just one my part of my app. Based on the option chose by user fragment will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact problem in my  case is I am trying to put **listview inside scrollview.**  and thats  **NOT RECOMMENDED** in general. But I have managed to expand my listview. though its not scroll able its better then before. Below is the code I have added in my constructor

```
ListView lst = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] arrayList = new String[] { "ad", "sfsd", "sfsf", "asfsfs",
                "ssfsff", "llkllk", "4323" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayList);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, lst);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) lst.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight;

        // arraylist list is in which all data is kept

        lp.height = height;
        lst.setLayoutParams(lp);

        lst.setAdapter(adapter);
```